# How to change the color of scatter plot with pandas?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm trying to color the dots of scatter plot by the values of a column in a CSV file. I'm using pandas dataframe to work with the file and I tried it with a simple file like this:

[image]

With this file it works well but when I try to do it with the CSV that I need this is the error:

```
Error: c of shape (31,) not acceptable as a color sequence for x with size 31, y with size 31
```

This is the column that I'm using to color the dots:

[image]

My function to read CSV and plot it:

```
       def readCSV(self):
        try:
            nombre, ok = QtWidgets.QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(self, 'Open file', "*.csv")

            if ok:
                df = pd.read_csv(nombre, delimiter=";")
                #print (df)
                ax = self.figure.add_subplot(111)
                ax.clear()
                df.groupby('Handle').plot(y='Frecuencia Inicial (MHz)', x='TOA (ns)', kind='line', ax=ax, title='Frec VS TOA')
                df.groupby('Handle').plot(y='Frecuencia Inicial (MHz)', x='TOA (ns)', kind='scatter', ax=ax, c=df['Causa DDW'])
                self.canvas.draw()

        except Exception as e:
            print("Error:", e)
```

I also tried:

```
 df.groupby('Handle').plot(y='Frecuencia Inicial (MHz)', x='TOA (ns)', kind='scatter', ax=ax, c='Causa DDW')
```

but this didn't work and this is the error:

```
Error: 'str' object has no attribute 'shape'
```

What am I missing or doing wrong? Thanks in advance!

Comment: You cannot supply a column name for the `c` argument. If you want to do that, is using seaborn an option for you?

Comment: I want to plot two columns of my csv and assign de color of the scatter plot by a third colum, if seaborn let me do it, it will be an option!

Comment: I guess it would. If you need further help, consider providing a [mcve].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case someone need it! I just found a solution, probably not the best but it works.  I asociate all the values from that column to a color in a map and just use it for "c":

```
 col = df['Causa DDW'].map({'EXC': 'g', 'MOD': 'b', 'DUR': 'r'})
```